# My code with CSV write has stopped recognizing writer as being valid

Tags: python, csv

My csv writer doesn't want to work anymore, it still creates a file, but it doesn't add any data to the file. I have found that `csv.writer(f)`doesn't work.The error that pops up is`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'writer'.

I honestly don't know what is going wrong. I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1XiCh-mGCA&t=165s as my model. I have also gone to https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html looked at how they write it, but I can't seem to find out what the major difference is between mine and theirs. I feel like a fool asking this, but I can't seem to get it.

*edit with more context, it wouldn't let me post more.

```
def full():
    wks1 = gc.open('RubricAutomation').worksheet(sheetname[lb.curselection()[0]])
    marklist = list(zip(orgid[2:], mark[2:],late[2:])) #combines student ID and marks for CSV
    toplist = list(zip(names[2:], commentList[2:])) #combines student names and comments for D2L
    sorting = lambda toplist: toplist[0]
    toplist.sort(key=sorting)

    with open(location + asgnName + ".csv", 'w',  newline='') as f:  ## opens new csv file into location and adds name from gspread
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['OrgDefinedId', asgnName + " Points Grade", "End-of-Line Indicator"])
        for i in marklist:
            writer.writerow([ i[0],i[1] ,"#"])
```

Comment: csv.writer(f) worked for me? python 3.6.5 csv 1.0

Comment: I'm on 3.7. must be an update thing?

Comment: make sure you didnt assign something to csv previously?

Comment: @CalviHobbes, can you provide the code before the `with` statement?

Comment: You must have created a local function named `csv()`.

Comment: @CalvinHobbes Can you share the complete code that you are running from the import statement?

Comment: It's not from updating to 3.7..... Try `print(dir(csv.writer))` and it will show you information about what it is.

Comment: John Gordon , i think you got it. I feel so dumb. Thank you